# Split entries in columns

Tags: entries, layout

I'm trying to build a feed of entries in a column grid. Something like that:

```
<div class="column">
 <a class="entry">First entry</a>
 <a class="entry">Fourth entry</a>
</div>

<div class="column">
 <a class="entry">Second entry</a>
 <a class="entry">Fifth entry</a>
</div>

<div class="column">
 <a class="entry">Third entry</a>
 <a class="entry">Sixth entry</a>
</div>
```

How do I achieve that? In my head `.batch(3)` only works horizontally for rows.

*Edit:* To make it more clearly, that's my goal and the reason for columns instead of rows:

[image: Column Grid]

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy twig function available to do this, but the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715777/how-to-make-3-columns-table-with-twig-in-symfony2) should be able to help you.

```
{% set columns = 3 %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% if loop.first or loop.index0 is divisibleby(columns) %}
        <tr>
    {% endif %}

    <td>{{ entry.title }}</td>

    {% if loop.last and loop.index is not divisibleby(columns) %}
        {% for n in range(low=columns - (loop.index % columns), high=1, step=-1) %}
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if loop.last or loop.index is divisibleby(columns) %}
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's a good start, but how can that work with different columns as `<div>`s?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop through all entries first and divide the entries into three arrays. Then using a combination of `id` and `fixedOrder` you can create three more entries calls to loop through each column and it's entries.

This would make a nice dynamic solution that doesn't need refactoring as more entries are added.

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#fixedOrder
https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#id

Comment: Sounds great! Can you give me a boost with a small example of the syntax? I don't know how exactly to accomplish this with twig.